# Android : AlarmManager triggers anytime

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have following piece of code which should be trigger alarm after 2 days. However It gets triggered after every 2 hours, some users says they get it after every 5 mins too.

```
settingDB.updateSetting("Notification",1);
Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MINUTE,01);
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
//Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

// MyView is my current Activity, and AlarmReceiver is the
// BoradCastReceiver

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Setting.this, TimeAlarm.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Setting.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
//Log.w("alarm set for " , Calendar_Object.getTime().toString ());

/*
 * The following sets the Alarm in the specific time by getting the long
 * value of the alarm date time which is in calendar object by calling
 * the getTimeInMillis(). Since Alarm supports only long value , we're
 * using this method.
 * 3*1000*24*3600
 */

//alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(),3600*1000**24,pendingIntent);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000*2, pendingIntent);
```

Could you please help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The calendar object passed to alarm manager is set to a fixed time. This will cause the alarm to go off when that time comes.

Comment: That's the issue. I'd just like to add, that if you want to add a certain amount of days to the calendar, you can use this: `Calendar_Object.add (Calendar.DATE, numberOfDaysToAdd)`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.What I want is to trigger the alarm after every two days. Its repeating alarm. However it keeps triggering after every two hours or sometime many times. Should I removeCalendar_Object.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MINUTE,01);
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Answer (score 1):

you could also do this

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                + 60*1000,timeofAlarm pendingIntent);
```

The calendar object you passed seems to do the damage. Follow my example above , once the alarm will go off after like a min. Just to check if the alarm is working,(you may want to add anytime there ,its upto you).

**Realtime** is useful(and perhaps recommended) if you want your alarm to go off every given time, irrespective of user time state